# Undefined index using MySQL, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, xampp

I searched through similar questions, but I wasn't able to find fix my issue. How do I go about debugging a MySQL problem in PHP such as this? It's always really time consuming to find the cause of these errors. It's so much easier to find/fix errors in JavaScript.

Errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: role in C:\xampp\htdocs\Noobs_Search\serverCode\findPlayers.php on line 48
>
> Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\Noobs_Search\serverCode\findPlayers.php on line 49

It's referring to these lines:

```
$role   = $row['role'];
$g      = $row['gender'];
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

require "connect.php";

$searchBy   = $_GET["field"]; 
$searchText = $_GET["text"];

$playerSQL  =   "SELECT * 
                 FROM vw_playerTeamName";

if( isset($GET_["role"]) )
{
    $role       = $_GET["role"];
    $playerSQL .= " AND role = $role";//  .= is same as +=
}

if( isset($GET_["gender"]) )
{
    $gender     = $_GET["gender"];
    $playerSQL .= " AND gender = $gender";//  .= is same as +=
}

$result = $mysqli->query($playerSQL);

$pTable =   "<div class='table'>
        <div class='heading'>
            <div class='cell'>ID</div>
            <div class='cell'>First</div>
            <div class='cell'>Last</div>
            <div class='cell'>Email</div>
            <div class='cell'>Team</div>
            <div class='cell'>Gender</div>
            <div class='cell'>Role</div>
        </div>";

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $ID     = $row['ID'];
    $first  = $row['first'];
    $last   = $row['last'];
    $email  = $row['email'];
    $team   = $row['team_name'];
    $role   = $row['role'];
    $g      = $row['gender'];

    $pTable .=  "<div class='row'>
                    <div class='cell'>$ID</div>
                    <div class='cell'>$first</div>
                    <div class='cell'>$last</div>
                    <div class='cell'>$email</div>
                    <div class='cell'>$team</div>
                    <div class='cell'>$g</div>
                    <div class='cell'>$role</div>
                </div>";
}

$pTable .= "</div>";

$mysqli->close();

echo $pTable;
?>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    
    $('#search').click(function()
    {
        var searchField = $("#searchType").val();
        var searchText  = $("#searchText").val();
        var g           = $("input[name=gender]:checked").val();
        var r           = $("input[name=role]:checked").val();
        
        $.get("serverCode/findPlayers.php",
        {
            field:searchField,
            text:searchText,
            role:r,
            gender:g
        },function(response)
        {
            $("#placeholder").html(response);
        });

    });
    
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<?php

$doc = "<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Noobs Search Page</title>
                    <script src='clientCode/jquery-1.12.2.min.js'></script>
                    <script src='clientCode/search.js'></script>
                    <link href='css/tableStyle.css' rel='stylesheet'>
                </head>
            <body>
            
                <select id='searchType'>
                    <option value='first'>First Name</option>
                    <option value='last'>Last Name</option>
                    <option value='email'>Email</option>
                </select>
                
                <input id='searchText' type='text' name='text'>
                
                <p>Role<br>
                    <input type='radio' name='role' value='Pion'>Pion
                    <input type='radio' name='role' value='Captain'>Captain
                    <input type='radio' name='role' value='Assistant Captain'>Assistant Captain
                </p>
                
                <p>Gender<br>
                    <input type='radio' name='gender' value='M'>Male
                    <input type='radio' name='gender' value='F'>Female
                </p>
                
                <p>
                    <input type='button' name='search' id='search' value='search'>
                    <input type='button' name='clear' value='clear'>
                </p>
                
                <div id='placeholder'></div>

            </body>
        </html>";
        
echo $doc;
?>
```

Comment: Can you `print_r` the `$result->fetch_array()`

Comment: try to do print_r($result->fetch_array()) before the while loop and then you will get your array data as key => value the key is the index try to use the same key which is in the result you get

Comment: What do I look for in the array?



Array ( [0] => 4 [ID] => 4 [1] => Esme [first] => Esme [2] => Torosa [last] => Torosa [3] => eeyoro@mail.abc [email] => eeyoro@mail.abc [4] => 1 [team_id] => 1 [5] => The Ups [team_name] => The Ups )

Comment: If `$role` and `$gender` aren't set (i.e. they're not in the GET request) they're not added to the mysqli query, therefore `$row['role']` and `$row['gender']`are undefined in the result returned by the mysqli query, hence the errors. Check that the expected values are being obtained in your JavaScript, and handle cases where the variables aren't set in your PHP code.

Comment: Just to add, even if the mysqli query was populated with the radio button values, you'd end up with something like `SELECT * FROM vw_playerTeamName AND role = $role AND gender = $gender` which is syntactically incorrect: you'd need to put in a WHERE clause and put single quotes around the variables, since they appear to be strings.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have it misspelled it's $_GET

```
 if( isset($_GET["role"]) )
{
    $role       = $_GET["role"];
    $playerSQL .= " AND role = $role";//  .= is same as +=
}

if( isset($_GET["gender"]) )
{
    $gender     = $_GET["gender"];
    $playerSQL .= " AND gender = $gender";//  .= is same as +=
}
```

Comment: <?php

    require "connect.php";
    var_dump($_GET);

?>

post back what you get it seems that data is not being sent over

Answer (score 0):

Try to reformat your if statement to this and add `WHERE` on you `$platerSQL`.

```
$playerSQL  =   "SELECT * 
                 FROM vw_playerTeamName";

if( isset($GET_["role"]) )
{
    $role       = $_GET["role"];
    $playerSQL .= " WHERE role = '$role'";//  .= is same as +=

    if( isset($GET_["gender"]) )
    {
        $gender     = $_GET["gender"];
        $playerSQL .= " AND gender = '$gender'";//  .= is same as +=
        //$playerSQL will be SELECT * FROM vw_playerTeamName WHERE role = '$role' AND gender = '$gender'
    }

    //if there is no gender playerSQL will be SELECT * FROM vw_playerTeamName WHERE role = '$role'
}

elseif( isset($GET_["gender"]) )
{
    $gender     = $_GET["gender"];
    $playerSQL .= " WHERE gender = '$gender'";//  .= is same as +=
    // $playerSQL will be SELECT * FROM vw_playerTeamName WHERE gender = '$gender'

}

$result = $mysqli->query($playerSQL);
```

Because your old statement makes your query string into this if you have both condition in true. You lack on the `WHERE` condition on your query string.

```
$playerSQL  =   "SELECT * FROM vw_playerTeamName AND role = $role AND gender = $gender";
```